# JavaScript .hide('.var:after')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using JavaScript I have managed to create a script that can determine if the user is creating a single image canvas or a multiple image one, if the canvas has only one image I have successfully applied an :after with see through border to suggest wrapping image area that will be lost. But if it has more than one image it needs to hide this :after as there won't be a wrapping style.

Things I have tried ---

```
$('.seethoughborder:after').hide();
$('.seethoughborder:after').css('opacity', '0');
$('.seethoughborder').removeClass('seethoughborder');
```

Is there any other way to hide an :after?

```
var counter = 0;
        $('.absolute.Divholder').each(function() {
            counter++;
            // console.log(counter);
        });

        if( counter == 1 ) {
            $('.seethoughborderless').addClass('seethoughborder');
            document.write(" <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/assets/lowres.css'> "); 
            // apply the wrap effect 
        }else{
            $('.errorvaltestdiv').css('z-index', '1 !important');
            // the css wont be included
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you have applied the `:after` to `.seethoughborder`, removing `.seethoughborder` class from the element should work. This is the best approach. I assume the "seeth**r**oughborder" typo isn't affecting things?

Comment: Daft question, but elsewhere in your code is it `seethroughborder`, and you've just missed the "r" in "through" when trying to hide the `:after`?

Comment: You can not access `:after` and `:before` element using jQuery

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.seethroughborder:after').hide();
$('.seethroughborder:after').css('opacity', '0');
$('.seethroughborder').removeClass('seethroughborder');
```

Is it possible that you missed an "r" in each of your attempted solutions?

Answer (score 0):

try this with little css:

**CSS**

```
.seethoughborder.hiddenafetr:after{
   display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.seethoughborder').addClass('hiddenafetr');
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but I had the idea of includiong the css that does this in another file and only including said file when needed, but that didn't work either